# rails undefined method for a model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

I'm having a very strange error for my model.

My view code has:

```
Pickup by: <%= link_to Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post).volunteer.name, Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post).volunteer %>
```

but the page cannot be rendered. It shows:

```
NoMethodError in Posts#index

Showing /Users/rails_projects/pickup/app/views/posts/_post.html.erb where line #31 raised:

undefined method `volunteer' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #31):

28:                 </div>
29:             <% else %>
30:             
31:                 Pickup by: <%= link_to     Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post).volunteer.name, Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post).volunteer %>
32:             <% end %>
33:         <% end %>
34:     </li>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/index.html.erb



Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:31:in   `_app_views_posts__post_html_erb___3981341078159890289_70243818995260'
app/views/posts/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_posts_index_html_erb__1562091740607633290_70243844957440'
```

In rails console, I tried to call the volunteer method with no problem:

```
1.9.2-p290 :016 > Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post11)
Trip Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."pickedpost_id" = 11 LIMIT 1
 => #<Trip id: 10, pickedpost_id: 11, volunteer_id: 30, created_at: "2012-05-12 16:49:50",   updated_at: "2012-05-12 16:49:50"> 

1.9.2-p290 :017 > Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post11).volunteer.name
Trip Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" WHERE "trips"."pickedpost_id" = 11 LIMIT 1
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 30 LIMIT 1
 => "Ari Runte"
```

Actually not only volunteer method, all the method I tried to call on the trip object yield a undefined method error, even Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post11).id

I tried to render the Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post) and page renders the trip object fine.

```
Pickup by: #<Trip:0x007fc5d4866608>
```

What could be the problem?

To add some observations:

when I change the code to

```
<%= link_to Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post).some_invalid_method, ....%>,
```

The page renders

```
undefined method `some_invalid_method' for #<Trip:0x007fc5d6ec8fd0>
```

Compare with

```
undefined method `volunteer' for nil:NilClass
```

Why the page renders "Nil" for trip object when the method is actually legal?

Thanks

Comment: Are you executing that line on the view only one time for one trip, or multiple times for many trips? Its seems like it could be nil for one of the iterations...

Comment: The error means that `Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post)` returns `nil`. In other words: the trip you are trying to retrieve from the database doesn't exist. If you show some more of your view code someone maybe able to help you debug this.

Comment: It's post index pages shows a lot of posts. So it's executing multiple times. I'll double check if that's the case

Comment: Then youre getting nil for one or more of the post lookups.

Comment: You could add a line in the view like the following to track the problem:
<%= debugger unless Trip.find_by_pickedpost_id(post) =>
So your server will stop for debugging just before breaking

Comment: Thanks for the help! It actually is one post fail to look up a trip.

Comment: Thanks, haven't considered that, even though it was right infront of my eyes ;P